# Appendix without sections ?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

There is only one appendix chapter in my thesis, which Latex defaults as Appendix A. However, I need it to show up as only "Appendix" without A or 1. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve that.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 16):

You can change the `secnumdepth` to 0 in the appendix. This means that section numbering is switched off for all levels (parts, chapters, sections) after the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second}
\lipsum[2]

\appendix
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image: appendix without numbering]

Comment: Or `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` if `book` or `report` are used.

Comment: What is the purse of the `\appendix` command? I tried removing it and it seems that it makes no difference to the section numbering and ToC creation...

Comment: @Konrad: You're right, `\appendix` isn't needed here. This command switches from numerical to alphabetical section numbering, but since we're not showing any section numbers for the appendices in this example, it's not needed in this case.

Comment: @Jake Thanks very much for the useful explanation.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to suppress the numbering only for the appendix, but keep the numbering for other sectional units (i.e. sections, subsections inside the appendix), then you can redefine the commands `\thechapter` and `\thesection` just before the appendix:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A regular chapter}

\appendix
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\chapter{Only Appendix}
\section{Test section in Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using \chapter* (or \section*) for the appendix title should do the trick.

Comment: But then it doesn't show up in the table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

I went into the class file to do this. Essentially, there's something that looks like so:

```
\renewcommand\appendix{\par\UTD@appendixtrue
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
```

I changed it to this:

```
\renewcommand\appendix{\par\UTD@appendixtrue
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\ }}
```

This removes the letter but there's a white space in the ToC after APPENDIX. Win-some-lose-some. Hopefully someone get's a nicer solution someday.